# Building for Mac Catalyst with Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, mac-catalyst

Has anybody using Crashlytics been able to compile their iOS app for Mac Catalyst?

I tried building one of our iOS apps for Catalyst but I got the following error:

```
ld: in /Users/foo/bar/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSInternalReport.o), building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, file '/Users/foo/bar/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics' for architecture x86_64
```

I've updated to the latest version of Crashlytics using Cocoapods. Since CL already works on macOS, I would think it might be possible to link to the correct x86 library with Catalyst.

Answer (score 1):

Previously Firebase Crashlytics was not supported by the Mac Catalyst. In the new version of Firebase Crashlytics (6.15.0), they have provided the support.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current workaround. It does not let me use Crashlytics with Catalyst, but I can continue to create both Catalyst and iOS builds.

1. Clone your usual build target.
2. Enable Catalyst on the new target.
3. Add a section to the Podfile for the new target.
4. Include all required pods in the new target *except* Fabric and Crashlytics.
5. `pod install`
6. In the source code, conditionally build Crashlytics-dependent code using `#if canImport(Crashlytics)`
7. Continue to build the iOS app from the old target. Use the new target for Catalyst builds.

Comment: Actually I duplicate build target. According to your first step.
How to perform your step 2 to step 7. I do not Understand.
I am facing same problems